# Can't smoothly animate flexbox-direction

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transitions

I am changing flex-direction in hover but i want that it should be done smoothly but it is making a shock or jerk in changing direction.
I have also used transition and animation but it still shows error.

```
.a {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   transition:all 1 s linear;
 }
.a::hover {
   flex-direction:column-reverse;
   color: blue;
 }
```

Comment: What error does it shows?

Comment: this is making a jerk in changing flex-direction

Answer (score 2):

`flex-direction` is not [*animatable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

You can't smoothly transition from one value to another. Therefore, you need to come up with a different animation, using any of the properties in the link above.

**Note**: If you want your animations to be light and work smoothly on any device, you should try to only animate using `transform` and `opacity` (most animations can be performed with the these two alone).

---

However, there is a solution which generally works with non-animatable properties. It involves the following steps:

1. Make a invisible clone of the element, with the property you want to animate changed to the new value, same width and height and place it at the same exact position as the original.
2. Animate the element(s) involved from their current position to the position in the clone, using `translate`
3. Replace original with clone (and make clone visible).

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search gave [this result](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/eJGrPN) (not mine) which seems to achieve your goal with a bit of additional javascript and usage of TweenLite library. The main logic is located in `layout()` function:

```
function layout() {

    group.classList.toggle("reorder");  

    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {

        var box = boxes[i];

        var lastX = box.x;
        var lastY = box.y;   

        box.x = box.node.offsetLeft;
        box.y = box.node.offsetTop;

        // Continue if box hasn't moved
        if (lastX === box.x && lastY === box.y) continue;

        // Reversed delta values taking into account current transforms
        var x = box.transform.x + lastX - box.x;
        var y = box.transform.y + lastY - box.y;  

        // Tween to 0 to remove the transforms
        TweenLite.fromTo(box.node, 0.5, { x, y }, { x: 0, y: 0, ease });    
    } 
}
```

For each element that is in the flex layout it takes the last x and y coordinates, as well as current coordinates after the layout direction change, and based on these two, animates the transition and using `transform` css property.

Comment: dear user i m just a student yet please tell me the proper way to add that script

Comment: dear user i'm just a student yet please tell me the proper way to add that script.I have not added any script yet so if you tell me it will be good fro me.(thank you)